# GnuPG (gpg) specify multiple keyservers

Tags: gnupg

Specifying multiple keyservers doesn't seem to work correctly, and `gpg` always uses just the first key server. I have the following two lines in my `dirmngr.conf`:

```
keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org
keyserver https://keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

gpg version: 2.4.5

Comment: This looks like a typo... confirm your syntax

Answer (score 1):

There is no such scheme as `https`. For key servers that use HTTPS you should use scheme `hkps`. The 2nd line in your example should be as follows:

```
keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com
```